# Convert from string to double and int - C++

Tags: c++, string

I would like to know how I can convert `3 x^ 2` (text is given with spaces)
to `double c = 3` and `int d = 2`.

My solution

```
istream & operator>> (istream & in, Monomial &m) {
    char dummy1, dummy2;
    in>> m.coefficient >> dummy1 >> dummy2>> m.degree;
    return in;
}
```

works for `3x^2`, but fails for `1x` or `1`.

The input looks like

```
1
2
1x
2x
3x^2
3 x^ 3
```

and for each line, the coefficient should be the first number and degree the last number.

Comment: In "1" what is the first and what the last number?

Comment: So, you want to ignore what is in between?

Comment: If you want to parse an expression - you want to solve - and you plan to support more complex ones later, then you should take a look at parser generators.

Answer (score 1):

in case your input will be in the same format ** A x* B **, so i suggest to use STL, this how your main() can look like :

```
int main() {

    std::string equation = "233 X^ 36";
    std::string delimiter = " ";
    std::string tmp;

    tmp = equation.substr(0, equation.find(delimiter));
    double duble = std::stod(tmp);

    tmp = equation.substr(equation.rfind(delimiter));
    int integer = std::stoi(tmp);

    std::cout<< duble << " " << integer << std::endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

this a dummy code, but i hope it's enough to make my point clear.

Answer (score 1):

1. What you are trying to read in is **not quite trivial**.
2. Read about **[Recursive Descent Parsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser)**.
3. If you name your **input tokens**, you have:
   `enum token_t { tk_number, tk_x, tk_xcaret, tk_end };` (`tk_end` is used when you reach the end of stream).
4. Your **input** may be described as one of the following lines:

   ```
   tk_end // empty input
   tk_number
   tk_number tk_x
   tk_number tk_xcaret tk_number
   ```
5. You must solve two problems:

   - how to convert the **input** from characters [**to tokens**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)
   - once you are able to read the input as tokens, how to check the correct **[order of tokens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing)**

See below a tokenizer for your problem.

*Welcome to SO and good luck!*

```
enum token_t { tk_end, tk_number, tk_x, tk_xcaret };

double number;

token_t get_token(istream& is )
{
  ws(is); // skip white-spaces

  switch (is.peek()) // what's the next character?
  {

  case EOF:
    return tk_end; // end of stream reached

  case 'x':
    is.get(); // skip x
    if ('^' != is.peek())
      return tk_x;
    else
      return is.get(), tk_xcaret; // skip ^ and return

  default:
    if (!(is >> number))
      throw "number expected";
    return tk_number;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution with [regular expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex):

```
std::pair<double, int> parse(const std::string& str) {
    static const std::regex regex(
        R"#(\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(\s*x(?:\^\s*(\d+))?)?\s*)#");

    std::smatch match;
    if (std::regex_match(str, match, regex)) {
        if (match[2].matched) {
            if (match[3].matched)
                return {std::stod(match[1].str()), std::stoi(match[3].str())};
            else
                return {std::stod(match[1].str()), 1};
        }
        else
            return {std::stod(match[1].str()), 0};
    }

    throw std::invalid_argument{"Bad expression"};
}

int main() {
    auto p1 = parse("1.2");
    std::cout << p1.first << ' ' << p1.second << std::endl;     // 1.2 0

    auto p2 = parse("3.4 x");
    std::cout << p2.first << ' ' << p2.second << std::endl;     // 3.4 1

    auto p3 = parse("5.6 x^ 78");    
    std::cout << p3.first << ' ' << p3.second << std::endl;     // 5.6 78
}
```

I used simple expressions `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` for `double` and `\d+` for `int`. You might want to adjust them to your particular input format.